# Selenium. child xpath selector as as pointer to parent element

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver, selector

So let's say my html structure have couple of similar div elements.

```
body/div/...
body/div/...
body/div/...
body/DIV/div[@class='class']
```

I would like to access the last one. But the one that is upper-cased.
So "//body/div/" selector will find many, but not related elements. 
And "//div/div[@class='class']" will select the child div, not the upper case parent.

Comment: can you give precise HTML...,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`parent`](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp) to select the parent of a given element:

`//div/div[@class='class']/parent`

If you want to be more verbose, you can also select a parent by a given tag name:

`//div/div[@class='class']/parent::div`

Comment: You beat me by seconds. :-)

Comment: I knew it has to be something simple. Thanks !